# Склонение слов: "лошадьми" или "лошадями"

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: "лошадьми" или "лошадями"? Мне кажется, что "лошадьми", но почему тогда "дверями", а не "дверьми"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как известно, в творительном падеже многих существительных допустимы обе формы - лошадьми и лошадями, дверьми и дверями, причем более употребительными считаются  первые варианты, а вторые рассматриваются как книжные и в той или иной степени устарелые.  При нормативных формах "костями, плетями" сохраняется во фразеологических оборотах форма с ударяемым окончанием -(ь)ми: лечь костьми, наказание плетьми (Розенталь Д.Э.)

Answer (score 1):

В Грамматике-80 под редакцией Лопатина указывается основное окончание АМИ и вариантное окончание МИ у существительных дверь, дочь, лошадь. Дверями и дверьми - равноправные варианты, дочерьми и лошадьми  - основная форма, дочерями и лошадями - разговорная форма.

Comment: Грамматика - 80 под ред. Лопатина??? Грамматика - 80 была под ред. Шведовой.  Есть еще "Краткая русская грамматика" , лет на 10 позже, вот она под. редакцией Шведовой и Лопатина. Называть ее Грамматикой - 80 некорректно. Да еще и опуская фамилию Шведовой.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и "дверьми", и "лошадями". Обычно форма выбирается из соображений ритмичности ерчи.

Answer (score 0):

В орфографическом словаре написано лошадьми. Откуда взяли лошадями?

Comment: Правописание-это не разговорная речь. Говорить тоже нужно правильно, а не как Хрущев,как слышишь, так и пишешь. Сейчас говорят: звОнят,ложут. Куда мы придем?

Comment: У нас продаются новогодние открытки «с лошадями». Можно ли и нужно ли говорить:«с лошадьми»? Может быть, формы несут разный смысл, и мы хотим отразить его в речи и на письме? Например, картинки с лошадями – это много картинок, а на каждой картинке по одной лошади. 
Другие примеры: «Что касается кучера, к нему предъявлялись следующие требования: он должен был отлично управляться с лошадями». Из Достоевского: « Кучер исчез вместе с лошадьми, одновременно исчезли еще некоторые крестьяне из деревни».