# Дверьми или дверями?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Лошади — но лошадьми. Люди — людьми. Значит, по логике получается, что "дверь — дверьми", так? Но, по-моему, куда чаще говорят "дверями". Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта верны. Причем и для слова "лошадь" тоже.

К тому же [повтор вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)